# why does returning a map.insert().second introduce unreachable memory?

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
  ~A()
  {
        for (itr = mymap.begin(); itr != mymap.end() ++itr)
        {
           delete itr->second //the map look like this <std::string , T*>
        } 
  }



 A::Addnew(std::string name)
    {
       return mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string,T*>(name, new T)).second;
    }
```

introduces a memory leak, but if I change the `AddNew()` member function to:

```
itr = mymap.find(name);
if(itr == mymap.end())
{
   return mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string,T*>(name, new T)).second;
}
```

then there is no memory leak.

It seems like if I called the first case accidentally, I will introduce lots of new T, but my `mymap.size()` cannot keep track of it. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Use `std::make_pair` or `{a, b}` in C++11, and don't use `new` and `delete`. Use a smart pointer if you're hard-set on a pointer.

Comment: thanks for your advise, but I am just curious.

Comment: Does `insert(std::pair<name, new T>)` even compile? Looks like it should be `insert(std::pair<std::string,T*>(name, new T))` (or `insert(std::make_pair(name, new T))` ?!

Comment: sorry I am just being lazy on typing. I updated it.

Comment: `boost::ptr_map` may help.

Comment: Even if the find test before insert introduce an extra seek, I would go for it, to avoid allocation and deletion, if the key exists.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map::insert()` is a no-op if the key already exists in the map.

If you try to insert a duplicate key, the first version of your code will leak the object it has allocated using `new`.

The second version does not have this problem since you don't call `new` unless you've established that the key doesn't exist in the map.

Two good ways to fix the leak are:

- store the objects by value;
- store smart pointers to objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your first AddNew function:
when you are inserting a member whose key have existed in the map,
you will create a T object,but you do not release it:

you can do like this:

```
A::Addnew(std::string name)
    {
       T *temp = new T;
       if(mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string,T*>(name, temp)).second)
           return true;
       else
        {
           delete temp;
           return false;
         }
    }
```